# DOS attacks using cmd and protection against them

Tags: security, cmd, ping, denial-of-service

After finding someones ip you can easily send pings to them to make DOS attacks. Me and my friend tried to make a defense against them and wanted to know how a low level attacker can send this DOS attacks. When one of us sent pings to the other using cmd when we were connected to the same modem(wifi) it succeed in sending pings. But when we were on different networks it failed and sent a message like "Request timed out". I assume this is a failure message but I've some questions in this matter.

I won't write the command to make DOS attacks since I don't want to encourage anyone in making those and anyone who is knowledgeable in this subject already knows how to do that.

//Assume that attacker knows the ip of the victim. 
Questions

1. Can a computer be successful enough to slow down the second computer if he sends infinite pings? If so in how much time(approximately.)(assume their computers are same.) What can be the worst result for the victim?
2. How can someone be successful in making DOS attacks to people who are connected into different networks from cmd? And how can I take measures against them?

Comment: This question is not directly related to programming and is better suited for [su].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work over the internet if the victim's router is set not to send ICMP replies to ping requests.

> Can a computer be successful enough to slow down the second computer
>   if he sends infinite pings? If so in how much
>   time(approximately.)(assume their computers are same.) What can be the
>   worst result for the victim?

Not significantly. What you need is an amplification attack - that is the victim's computer has to do more work than you for each request. Sending a reply to a ping is minimal work and involves sending the same amount of bytes back, so you are not slowing the victim machine anymore than your own.

> How can someone be successful in making DOS attacks to people who are
>   connected into different networks from cmd? And how can I take
>   measures against them?

You would be better off using a software tool to do this, or by setting up a botnet to do a distributed denial of service instead (DDoS). Usage of such tools are probably illegal depending on your jurisdiction and you should get full permission if testing this from the owners of all networks and systems where your traffic would flow.

Mitigating DDoS is the million dollar question. Services such as CloudFlare can help. It all depends on what you need to protect and who from.